# What is the MSSQL equivalent of MySQL's password function?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, function, passwords, alternate

What is the equivalent function in MSSQL Server for `PASSWORD()` function of MYSQL? I have to migrate MySQL queries into MSSQL Server.

Below is the sample query of my source code:-

```
Select * from users where username = 'demo' and pasword = PASSWORD('demo');
```

this function is being used for creating user account creating as well as authentication.

Comment: how are you using it? please provide an example.

Comment: PASSWORD() function for creating database credentials?

Comment: Yes, for both account creation and authentication. I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Actually the function PASSWORD() of MySql should not have been used to hash passwords. From the MySql [docu](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password):

> PASSWORD() is used by the authentication system in MySQL Server; you
>   should not use it in your own applications.

The problem is, that it uses an unsalted and fast hashing algorithm. This doesn't give you much protection, instead use a hash algorithm with a cost factor, like BCrypt SCrypt or PBKDF2. MySql does not offer such an algorithm, so you should calculate the hash in your development language.

I would strongly recommend to switch to a more safe algorithm, for backwards compatibility you can have a look at "defines" answer, he tried to implement the MySql behaviour:

[MySQL Hashing Function Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1543873/575765)

Comment: This is an existing application of the client in which i can not make any changes. I know this is the good way to use for password encryption. Buy my problem is that i have to convert MySQL queries to MSSQL. Any help in this regard?

Comment: @deltaforce - Then have a look ath the linked example, it's probably just a kind of double hash `sha1(sha1(password))`, maybe the [HASHBYTES](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx) function could be of help. It really hurts if you have to build such an unsafe function for MSSql.

Comment: @deltaforce - If it is really a simple unsalted double hash, it is even offered out of the box by cracker tools like [oclHashcat](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat/#features-algos).